# Split string into 4 characters, separated by a comma

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split, character

I need to spilt a character string into groups of 4 characters from the right of the string, and separate by a comma.

Example:
`"5707559"`  needs to be displayed as `0570,7559`, adding the leading zero if the string is a odd number (3 characters).

The original string (string that needs to be separated) is of variable lengths from a dataframe column:

```
    Strings  Fixed_Strings
    5707559  0570, 7559
    7502     7502
    302      0302
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
split_by_n <- function(string, n = 4) {
  missing_zeros_number <- (n - nchar(string)) %% n
  extended_string_with_zeros <- paste0(
    c(numeric(missing_zeros_number), string), 
    collapse = "")
  total_length <- nchar(extended_string_with_zeros)
  substring(
    extended_string_with_zeros, 
    seq(1, total_length, n), 
    seq(n, total_length, n)
   )
}
```

```
split_by_n("foo")
split_by_n("foobar")
```

```
# [1] "0foo"
# [1] "00fo" "obar"
```

Finally to use on vector:

```
lapply(c("foo", "foobar"), split_by_n)
```

```
#[[1]]
#[1] "0foo"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "00fo" "obar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = c("5707559", "7502", "302")
ngroup = 4
library(stringr)
y = str_pad(x, width = ngroup*ceiling(nchar(x)/ngroup), pad = "0")
sapply(y, function(s) {
    n = nchar(s)/ngroup
    paste(sapply(seq(n), function(i)
        substring(s, ngroup*i-(ngroup - 1), ngroup*i)), collapse = ",")
})
#   05707559        7502        0302 
#"0570,7559"      "7502"      "0302"
```